# create table with json php

Tags: php, html, json

I have a Json result like this :

Array (

```
[0] => Array (
     [Street] => Street_name 
     [status] => Best_Shop 
     [Shop] => Array ( [0] => Array ( 
                    [Name] => Bakery_Shop 
                    [Owner] => John
                    [Type] => 0 
                    [Food] => Cake 
                    [Drink] => Coffee 
                    [Best_Customer] => All
                    [a] => Good 
                    [b] => Normal
                    [c] => Bad  
               [1] => Array ( 
                    [Name] => Junk_Foodshop 
                    [Owner] => Mike
                    [Type] => 0 
                    [Food] => Burger 
                    [Drink] => Coke 
                    [Best_Customer] => All
                    [a] => Good 
                    [b] => Normal
                    [c] => Bad ) 
    [Rate] => Average 
    [Signature] => Boss ) )
```

And i am trying to create a shop table with rows displaying each stat like this :

```
Name          Owner Type Food   Drink    Best_Customer  a    b      c

Bakery_Shop   John   0   Cake   Coffee       All        Good Normal Bad

Junk_Foodshop Mike   0   Burger Coke         All        Good Normal Bad
```

I currently have this code written up and although i am getting the data its not quite working the way i want it to be.

```
****From json_shop.php****

function getAstCard(){
    $json = array();
    $json[0] = array(
        "Street" => "Street_name ",
        "status" => "Best_Shop ",
        "Shop" => $Shop,
        "Rate" => "Average ",
        "Signature" => $conf->get_IXAstUser()
    );
    return $json;
}
**Into jsonTable.php**

    <?php
    include 'json_shop.php';

    $AstCardTable.='<table style="width:990px;" id="shopcard">';
    $AstCardTable.='<thead>';
    $AstCardTable.='<tr>';
    $AstCardTable.='    
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Owner</th>
                            <th>Type</th>
                            <th>Food</th>
                            <th>Drink</th>
                            <th>Best_Customer</th>
                            <th>a</th>
                            <th>b</th>
                            <th>c</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>';

    $AstCard = getAstCard();
    if (count($AstCard) > 0) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($AstCard); $i++) {
            $AstCardRecord = $AstCard[$i];
                $AstCardTable.='<tr>';
                $AstCardTable.='<td>' . $AstCardRecord['Name'] . '</td>';
                $AstCardTable.='<td>' . $AstCardRecord['Owner'] . '</td>';
                $AstCardTable.='<td>' . $AstCardRecord['Type'] . '</td>';
                $AstCardTable.='<td>' . $AstCardRecord['Food'] . '</td>';
                $AstCardTable.='<td>' . $AstCardRecord['Drink'] . '</td>';
                $AstCardTable.='<td>' . $AstCardRecord['Best_Customer'] . '</td>';
                $AstCardTable.='<td>' . $AstCardRecord['a'] . '</td>';
                $AstCardTable.='<td>' . $AstCardRecord['b'] . '</td>';
                $AstCardTable.='<td>' . $AstCardRecord['c'] . '</td>';
                $AstCardTable.='</tr>';
        }
    } else {
        $AstCardTable.='<tr>';
        $AstCardTable.='<td style="font-family: Verdana;font-weight: bold;font-size: 12px;" colspan=9>Temporarily no data in the list</td>';
        $AstCardTable.='</tr>';
    }

    $AstCardTable.='</tbody>';
    $AstCardTable.='</table>';

    echo $AstCardTable;


    ?>
```

Does anyone with experience in this topic and see if any problem about my code? Any help would be greatly appreciated.Thank you .

Comment: You need to return `return $json[0]['Shop'];` from `getAstCard` method.

Comment: yes .I already call that function but it still not showing the output table

Comment: @art, I added my updated code below, Please check if it can resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return return `$json[0]['Shop'];` from `getAstCard` method.

Otherwise, change the variable in your loop a bit :

```
$AstCard = getAstCard();
$AstCardShop = $AstCard[0]['Shop'];
if (count($AstCardShop) > 0) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($AstCardShop); $i++) {
            $AstCardRecord = $AstCardShop[$i];

            $AstCardTable.='<tr>';
            $AstCardTable.='<td>' . $AstCardRecord['Name'] . '</td>';
            $AstCardTable.='<td>' . $AstCardRecord['Owner'] . '</td>';
            $AstCardTable.='<td>' . $AstCardRecord['Type'] . '</td>';
            $AstCardTable.='<td>' . $AstCardRecord['Food'] . '</td>';
            $AstCardTable.='<td>' . $AstCardRecord['Drink'] . '</td>';
            $AstCardTable.='<td>' . $AstCardRecord['Best_Customer'] . '</td>';
            $AstCardTable.='<td>' . $AstCardRecord['a'] . '</td>';
            $AstCardTable.='<td>' . $AstCardRecord['b'] . '</td>';
            $AstCardTable.='<td>' . $AstCardRecord['c'] . '</td>';
            $AstCardTable.='</tr>';
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks .it working but why it only show the row for bakery_shop .but not showing the row for Junk_Foodshop ?

Comment: `$AstCard[0]['Shop']` contains 2 elements. So, count of that variable should come as 2 and it should loop 2 times. Please check with the above code, I changed a little. You might checked with my previous code. If still you are facing the same issue, then do `echo count($AstCardShop); exit;` before the loop and check what is the count.